# How does the new Apple page fade in the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Apple](http://apple.com) changed their home page with a fade in effect that loads fast. Is this HTML 5 or jQuery?

Does anyone know how they did this?

Comment: html is just markup. this can be done using either Javascript or CSS3 transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this bit of javascript --> http://images.apple.com/global/scripts/ac_blackout.js.

Here it is after a run through http://jsbeautifier.org/:

```
AC.Blackout = Class.create({
    defaultOptions: {
        duration: 1.25,
        delay: 2,
        showOnce: false,
        showWhenReferredByApple: true
    },
    initialize: function (c, a, b) {
        this.uniqueIdentifier = a || Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
        this.options = Object.extend(Object.clone(this.defaultOptions), b);
        if (!this.shouldShow()) {
            return false
        }
        this._addBodyClass();
        Event.onDOMReady(function () {
            this.og = {};
            this.og.element = $(c);
            this.bo = {};
            this.bo.offsets = this.og.element ? this.og.element.cumulativeOffset() : [0, 0];
            this.images = [];
            if (this.options.showOnce) {
                this._setHasShown()
            }
            this._create();
            this.fade.bind(this).delay(this.options.delay)
        }.bind(this))
    },
    addImage: function (b, a) {
        this.preloadImage(b);
        if ( !! this._acceptImages) {
            this._addImage(false, b, a)
        } else {
            this._boundAddImage = this._addImage.bindAsEventListener(this, b, a);
            Event.observe(document.body, "ACBlackout:acceptImages", this._boundAddImage)
        }
    },
    preloadImage: function (c) {
        var b = function (d) {
            delete a
        };
        var a = new Image();
        a.onload = b;
        a.src = c
    },
    _addImage: function (a, c, b) {
        if (typeof this.images == "undefined") {
            return false
        }
        this.images.push(new AC.Blackout.Image(this.bo, c, b))
    },
    wasReferredByApple: function () {
        if (typeof this._wasReferredByApple !== "undefined") {
            return this._wasReferredByApple
        }
        this._wasReferredByApple = document.referrer.match(/^\w*:\/\/[^\.]*.apple.com/);
        if ( !! document.referrer.match(/\/home/)) {
            return false
        }
        return this._wasReferredByApple
    },
    shouldShow: function () {
        if (typeof this._shouldShow !== "undefined") {
            return this._shouldShow
        }
        if (/msie|MSIE 6/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            return this._shouldShow = false
        }
        this._shouldShow = true;
        if (this.options.showOnce) {
            if (!this.options.showWhenReferredByApple) {
                if (!this.wasReferredByApple()) {
                    return this._shouldShow = true
                }
            }
            try {
                typeof localStorage
            } catch (b) {
                return this._shouldShow = false
            }
            if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
                try {
                    var a = localStorage.getItem("ACBlackout-" + this.uniqueIdentifier);
                    this._shouldShow = (a == null) ? true : false
                } catch (b) {
                    return this._shouldShow = false
                }
            } else {
                if ("addBehavior" in document.body) {
                    document.body.addBehavior("#default#userData");
                    document.body.load("ACBlackout");
                    this._shouldShow = document.body.getAttribute("ACBlackout-" + this.uniqueIdentifier) == null ? true : false
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!this.options.showWhenReferredByApple) {
                if ( !! this.wasReferredByApple()) {
                    this._shouldShow = false
                }
            }
        }
        return this._shouldShow
    },
    _addBodyClass: function () {
        document.body.className += " ACBlackoutBody"
    },
    _setHasShown: function () {
        var a = new Date;
        a = a.getTime();
        try {
            typeof localStorage
        } catch (b) {
            return true
        }
        if (typeof localStorage !== "undefined") {
            try {
                localStorage.setItem("ACBlackout-" + this.uniqueIdentifier, a)
            } catch (b) {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if ("addBehavior" in document.body) {
                document.body.addBehavior("#default#userData");
                document.body.setAttribute("ACBlackout-" + this.uniqueIdentifier, a);
                document.body.save("ACBlackout");
                return true
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    },
    _create: function () {
        this.bo.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight > document.body.scrollHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.scrollHeight;
        if ($("ACBlackout")) {
            this.bo.element = $("ACBlackout")
        } else {
            this.bo.element = new Element("div", {
                id: "ACBlackout",
                "class": "ACBlackout",
                style: "height: " + this.bo.height + "px;"
            })
        }
        this._acceptImages = true;
        Event.fire(document.body, "ACBlackout:acceptImages", true);
        if (AC.Detector.isCSSAvailable("transition")) {
            this.bo.element.setVendorPrefixStyle("transition", this.options.duration + "s opacity ease-in")
        }
        if (AC.Detector.isIE()) {
            Element.insert(document.body, {
                bottom: this.bo.element
            })
        } else {
            Element.insert(document.body, {
                top: this.bo.element
            })
        }
        Element.removeClassName(document.body, "ACBlackoutBody")
    },
    fade: function () {
        if (AC.Detector.isCSSAvailable("transition")) {
            var b = function (c) {
                c.target.hide();
                c.target.removeVendorEventListener("transitionEnd", a)
            };
            var a = b.bindAsEventListener(this);
            this.bo.element.addVendorEventListener("transitionEnd", a);
            this.bo.element.setStyle("opacity: 0;")
        } else {
            this.bo.element.fade({
                duration: this.options.duration
            })
        }
    }
});
AC.Blackout.Image = Class.create({
    defaultOptions: {
        offsets: [0, 0],
        dimensions: false,
        duration: 0.75,
        delay: 0
    },
    initialize: function (b, c, a) {
        this.options = Object.extend(Object.clone(this.defaultOptions), a);
        this.bo = b;
        this.src = c;
        this._create();
        this.fadeIn.bind(this).delay(this.options.delay)
    },
    _create: function () {
        this.left = this.options.offsets[0];
        this.top = this.bo.offsets[1] + this.options.offsets[1];
        this.main = new Element("div", {
            "class": "ACBlackoutMain"
        });
        this.img = new Element("img", {
            src: this.src,
            "class": "ACBlackoutImg",
            style: "top: " + this.top + "px; left: " + this.left + "px;"
        });
        if (this.options.dimensions) {
            this.img.setStyle("width: " + this.options.dimensions[0] + "px; height: " + this.options.dimensions[1] + "px;")
        }
        if (AC.Detector.isCSSAvailable("transition")) {
            this.img.setStyle("opacity: 0");
            this.img.setVendorPrefixStyle("transition", this.options.duration + "s opacity ease-in")
        } else {
            this.img.hide()
        }
        this.bo.element.insert(this.main);
        this.main.insert(this.img)
    },
    fadeIn: function () {
        if (AC.Detector.isCSSAvailable("transition")) {
            this.img.setStyle("opacity: 1;")
        } else {
            this.img.appear({
                duration: this.options.duration
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you pull tis off Apple's site..?

Comment: +1 for the most direct answer. No point discussing hypotheicals - use the source luke!

Answer (score 6):

It is JavaScript. HTML5 is a markup language - it doesn't do dynamic things. But the way people are throwing around the term, you'd think it could cure world hunger.

It looks like they use the [Prototype library](http://www.prototypejs.org/) - probably for legacy reasons, now that jQuery has gained more traction. Or maybe they just prefer that library.

In plain JavaScript, you can fade a div with `window.setInterval()` and animating `style.opacity`.

Comment: Sure... I know, but javascript seems to be too basic for this clean effect. For Apple to use it!  Jquery maybe?

Comment: @Erik If they are using jQuery, which they are not, then they'd be using JavaScript. Effects are possible with JavaScript, some CSS or Flash/similar.

Comment: Is the effect layered you think?  or is it a page transition?

Comment: @Erik Yes it is layered over the main site. If you are talking about the meta tag for page transition, that is/was a proprietary IE thing.

Comment: Nice... I forgot about the opacity!